# Select2 Bootstrap4 Theme with Customized Botstrap4

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm totally new to scss and css compilation and have here a bootstrap 4.3.1 compiled css file that was customized with the following options:

```
    $enable-shadows: true;
    $enable-gradients: true;
    $enable-caret: false;
    $enable-rounded: false;
```

When I use a Select2-Bootstrap4-Theme like https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme it always looks like uncostumized bootstrap, though and not at all like the other fields. How can I make the Bootstrap4-Theme look like the customized bootstrap

Comment: hi did you work out how to do this in the end? I am new to this as well and am trying to find out how to customize the height. did you have to import variables from bootstrap into the theme project?

Comment: In the end I didn’t recompile like that but just created a css that overwrote settings. I work in a classical Java environment with out npm etc so I had to keep it time sensitive